# How to rotate point cloud to align with gravity direction?

Tags: python, opencv, 3d, point-clouds, calibration

I have a depth image of the scanning of two chairs and have converted it to a point cloud file (*.ply).

The problem is that the points are in the camera coordinate and I want to calibrate the coordinate and make it align with gravity direction. (i.e. make z-axis to align with gravity direction)

I do not know how to do it using python.

Is it already implemented in OpenCV? Any suggestions will be helpful. If the description of my question is unclear, please do let me know!

Thanks for your time!

Here is what the point cloud looks like as follows:

[Visualization of point cloud in MeshLab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qoq8.jpg)

[Visualization of point cloud in MeshLab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZY3z.jpg)

Here is the point cloud file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S2ja24zaSRa2if-Qi43mmqAg9HxLiZHE/view?usp=sharing

Here is how I read points from ply file：

```py
def read_ply(filename):
    """ read XYZ point cloud from filename PLY file. Code from VoteNet."""
    plydata = PlyData.read(filename)
    pc = plydata['vertex'].data
    # pc_array = np.array([[x, y, z] for x, y, z in pc])
    pc_array = np.array([[point['x'], point['y'], point['z']] for point in pc])
    return pc_array
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at transformation matrices?

Comment: @Marc Thanks very much for your comment.  I think I need to build an algorithm to detect the floor (or some other flat surfaces) and calculate the normal vector of the surface. Then I can get the transformation matrice according to the normal vector. The problem may be that I do not know how to automatically detect the floor. Do you konw is there any out-of-the-box algorithms?

Comment: Maybe you could use a Hough transform for plane detection? But that would probably need to assume that the floor is the largest plane in your dataset.